# Jquery and Dojo DataGrid problem

Tags: jquery, datagrid, dojo, load

I've a problem when I want to load a page that contains some dojo code. The page loaded doesn't display any information.

My index.html that loads the page, looks like that :

```
<html>
 <head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.5/dojo/dojo.xd.js" djConfig="parseOnLoad: true">
//to fill
</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.5/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="mainFrame">
<script type="text/javascript" >
$('#mainFrame').load('/Page.html');
</script>
</div>
    </body>
    <html>
```

My second page contains the code to display a DataGrid : Pahe.html

```
<html>
    <head>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.5/dojox/grid/resources/claroGrid.css'/>
       <script type="text/javascript" >
       dojo.require("dojox.grid.DataGrid");
       dojo.require("dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore");
       function prepare() {
          var data0 =[{FristName:'jean',LastName:'edu',Course:'english'}];
          var store0 = new dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore({
          data: {
          items: data0
          }
          });
          var grid0  = new dojox.grid.DataGrid({
          store: store0,
          structure: [
          {field: 'FirstName', name: 'FirstName', width:'auto'},
          {field: 'LastName', name: 'LastName', width:'auto'},
          {field: 'Course', name: 'Course', width:'auto'}
          ],
          rowsPerPage: 20,
          clientSort : true,
          rowSelector : '10px'
          }, "grid0");
          grid0.startup();
       }
       dojo.addOnLoad(prepare);
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="grid0"/>
    </body>
    </html>
```

When I run this code in a browser, I see nohting. However, I see with google chrome prospect tool that the browser loads the dataGrid of dojo...

I think it's a problem with the load of jquery because If I add the code to load the script of dojo in the 'Page.html', i'm able to see something...I guest that something is wrong with jquery and dojo...

Could you help me to solve that?

Thanks in advance,

bat

Answer (score 0):

Just thinking out loud here maybe, but you are calling $('#mainFrame') inline in the document above the corresponding "mainframe" div. Will that work? I would think that js call needs to be beneath the "mainframe" div in the document.

I would try moving that call out of the "head" and put it inline in the body somewhere after the "mainframe" div.

Comment: I change the code (edited on my thread). But I still have the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I went to look for the API docs for JQuery's load, but it brings up an empty page :-)

I'm not sure exactly what it does, particularly with HEAD elements, but if it's simply doing something like an innerHTML assignment, that won't work with Dojo's code loader or the CDN cross-domain loading going on.  The Dojo code you have likely expects to be executed at page load time.

Answer (score 0):

2 suggestions:

1- You might need the "base" grid CSS imported for the dojo grid.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.5/dojox/grid/resources/Grid.css">
```

2- You also might need to set a height on the data grid (in pixels...percentages don't work with the data grid).